# HTML Table - Buttons for Up, Down and Delete

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, events

I am working on a project using HTML5, CSS3, Javascript and Bootstrap.

The current page I'm having issues with has an HTML Table that requires four main functionalities: add new row, move row up, move row down, delete row.

To be more specific, I need it to be able to:

Provide the user the option to add an IP range to a new row at the bottom of the table.
Provide the new IP Range with an order number that follows the previously defined order. (Example: if there are 10 IP Ranges listed, the new IP Range should have an order number of 11)
Provide user buttons in each row to move an IP Range up or down in order.
Provide the user the option to delete an IP Range.

Right now I can add IP Ranges to a new row at the bottom of the table. I can move rows up and down. I can also delete a row.
Currently my code requires me to select the row I plan to move before I move it, which is a feature I would like to remove.

**What I need help with:**
*1. How can I remove the need to SELECT the row before doing these functionalities? Example: if the user presses the UP arrow in row 2, just move the IP Range from row 2 to row 1?
2. How can I automatically reorder the rows based on if a row is deleted? Example: if there exists an IP Range in the table, it should start with a value Order=1. Any subsequent IP Range rows 'n' should have a value of 1+n. If there are three IP Ranges in the table and the second IP Range is deleted, how can I ensure that the order will not be (1, 3) and instead (1, 2)?*

Note: the information in the table in the example provided is static but I will be filling dynamically from database. I will not know beforehand how many IP Ranges there are.

code:

```js
function SomeDeleteRowFunction() {
  // event.target will be the input element.
  var td = event.target.parentNode;
  var tr = td.parentNode; // the row to be removed
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}


//This function adds a user-input IP Range to the end of table body
function addEndIPRanges() {

  //Accessing table body
  var table = document.getElementById("myTableBody");

  //Insert row at end of table body (-1 appends)
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);

  //Insert 3 new cells into new row
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('addIPRange').value;

}

"use strict";
const tbody = document.querySelector("#table tbody");
let selected = null;
tbody.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let row = e.target.closest("tr");
  if (row === selected) {
    row.classList.toggle("selected")
    selected = null;
  } else {
    if (selected) {
      selected.classList.toggle("selected");
    }
    selected = row;
    row.classList.toggle("selected");
  }
});

function upNdown(direction) {
  let up, down;
  if (selected) {
    up = direction == "up" ? selected : selected.nextElementSibling;
    down = direction == "up" ? selected.previousElementSibling : selected;
    if (up && down) {
      tbody.insertBefore(up, down); // put up before down
      var temp = up.firstElementChild.textContent; // swap first cells' text content
      up.firstElementChild.textContent = down.firstElementChild.textContent;
      down.firstElementChild.textContent = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
tr {
    cursor: pointer
}

.selected {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<figure class="text-center mb-3">
  <h1 class="display-5">IP Range Management</h1>
</figure>

<hr>

<input type='text' id='addIPRange' />
<button style="text-align: center;" onclick="addEndIPRanges()">Add IP Range</button>


<hr>

<h4 class="iprangetableheader" style="text-align: center;">IP Ranges</h4>


<table id="table" style="margin: auto; width: 75%;">

  <thead>

    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th scope="col">Order</th>
      <th scope="col">IP Range</th>
      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody id="myTableBody">

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>255.255.255.255</td>
      <td><button onclick="upNdown('up');">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
        <button onclick="upNdown('down');">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>234.132.1.642</td>
      <td><button onclick="upNdown('up');">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
        <button onclick="upNdown('down');">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()">
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>24.32.2.25</td>
      <td><button onclick="upNdown('up');">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
        <button onclick="upNdown('down');">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>

<hr>
```

**Link to JS Fiddle: [What I've got so far](https://jsfiddle.net/Woftsare/yaem8f4p/4/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might look weird but it works:

You can send the `clicked button` as a `parameter` to the function and derive the `row` which it belongs to. That row is your required element.

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector("#table tbody");
function upNdown(direction,button) {
// Here button parameter is getting the button which is clicked
// Its parent element is a td whose parent element is a tr which is to be moved and voila
  let selected = button.parentElement.parentElement;
   let up, down;
  if (selected) {
    up = direction == "up" ? selected : selected.nextElementSibling;
    down = direction == "up" ? selected.previousElementSibling : selected;
    if (up && down) {
      tbody.insertBefore(up, down); // put up before down
      var temp = up.firstElementChild.textContent; // swap first cells' text content
      up.firstElementChild.textContent = down.firstElementChild.textContent;
      down.firstElementChild.textContent = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" style="margin: auto; width: 75%;">

  <thead>

    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th scope="col">Order</th>
      <th scope="col">IP Range</th>
      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody id="myTableBody">

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>255.255.255.255</td>
      <td><button onclick="upNdown('up',this);">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
        <button onclick="upNdown('down',this);">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>234.132.1.642</td>
      <td><button onclick="upNdown('up',this);">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
        <button onclick="upNdown('down',this);">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()">
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>24.32.2.25</td>
      <td><button onclick="upNdown('up',this);">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
        <button onclick="upNdown('down',this);">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction()">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

**This is how you can maintain the index:**

1. Add a class `ip-row` or whatever you want to all the `tr` elements which hold the ip.
2. Remember to give that class to only the elements which hold the ip otherwise it will index all the rows.
3. Take that class and insert the following code in the `delete` function and put it after you have removed the element like this-

```js
function SomeDeleteRowFunction() {
  // event.target will be the input element.
  var td = event.target.parentNode;
  var tr = td.parentNode; // the row to be removed
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  // Select all trs
  let trs = Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('.ip-row'))
  // Start index
  let index = 1;
  trs.forEach((tr) => { 
    // For all trs give a value to its first td which holds the index
    tr.querySelectorAll('td')[0].innerHTML = index;
    // increment the index
    index++
  })
}
```

Comment: Bejaj this works, thank you. Do you have any ideas for how to maintain a consistent linear order for numbers in column 1 if a row is deleted? Thanks again!

Comment: @Koldsoar I have updated my answer on how to maintain the index.